# How to configure Nemo's right-click "Open in Terminal" to launch "gnome-terminal"

Tags: gnome-terminal, nemo

I realize the default of the Nemo's right-click "Open in Terminal"
is to launch "gnome-terminal";
however, my installation is opening "xfce4-terminal" instead.

A while back when "gnome-terminal" was broken, I installed "xfce4-terminal" as an alternative.  I configured the system-wide defaults to call "xfce4-terminal" for the terminal.

After the issue with gnome-terminal was resolved, I moved the system-wide defaults back to gnome-terminal.  Nautilus starting using gnome-terminal again; however, **Nemo** continues to launch "xfce4-terminal".

I uninstalled "xfce4-terminal";
then the "Open in Terminal" feature of Nemo stopped working.

In attempts to resolve this issue I have done the following:

- Reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04
- Purged and reinstalled Nemo

Nemo still will launch only "xfce4-terminal".  It appears to be a problem in my home folder's Nemo configuration or some other per-user cache. 
I created a new user, and Nemo properly launched "gnome-terminal".

Can someone help me with where to check and fix Nemo's functionality
in my `/home/username` settings?

Is there some type of editable configuration to check what happens
when clicking on the "Open in Terminal" function?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Nemo uses the gsettings configuration.  This restored the intended behavior:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec gnome-terminal
```

On Ubuntu it's different for some reason:

```
$ gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec gnome-terminal
```

Comment: Actually, on Ubuntu, BOTH of those commands are required! The first one changes which terminal opens with **Ctrl + Alt + T**, and the 2nd command changes which terminal opens up with the right-click menu option in Nemo.

Comment: Note: I've detailed installing Nemo in Ubuntu here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1173861/327339. I really think it should be the default file manager in Ubuntu, NOT Nautilus.

Comment: Thanks. This also works on arch linux with xfce4: In my case: `gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec terminator`

Comment: For tilix: `gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec tilix`

Comment: the Ubuntu variant works on Fedora 37 running i3wm. Although, for "obvious" reasons, I use the `alacritty` terminal

Answer (score 51):

Google brought me here, so I'm reviving this thread in hope of saving at least one person from a few unnecessary headaches.

I'm using Debian and [the suggestion from L. D. James here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336587/114401) didn't work for me. So I took a look at Nemo's source code, and on [line 132 of **nemo-global-preferences.c**](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/015db702c7234d6c2ceda8707045186480dcc62e/libnemo-private/nemo-global-preferences.c#L132) I found that the (upstream) config schema is the following:

> org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal

I'm using Nemo as a substitute for Nautilus, and since I'm using Gnome3 instead of Cinnamon, for me this schema didn't even exist. So, I created it with the following command. After issuing this command, the 'Open in Terminal' action opens `gnome-shell`, in the correct directory:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec gnome-shell
```

Just replace `gnome-shell` in the command with whatever terminal you'd like to use. Ex: for `gnome-terminal`, use:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec gnome-terminal
```

And for [`terminator`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_(terminal_emulator)) (`sudo apt install terminator`) use:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec terminator
```

Comment: I don't understand how executing `gnome-shell` with bring up a preferring **terminal emulator**.  I tested what would happen if the command `gnome-shell` was executed.  It doesn't bring up a terminal.  On the particular computer running the test it returned this error message: `org.gnome.Shell already exists on bus and --replace not specified`.  It appears that you misunderstood the question.  I run Ubuntu, 16.04 at the time... currently 18.04 functions properly with the same schema.  By the way, default setting is `x-terminal-emulator`, which brings up `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: With above, replace gnome-shell with whatever terminal application you want to use and it should work.  Works on Arch...

Comment: you might want to try `gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec terminator` for 2023

Comment: Working on Fedora 37 under i3wm. Particularly for `alacritty` (you know, the best terminal)

Comment: Adding this note, if you have gsettings installed via apt and still cant access the utility from terminal (bash: command not found), you can install libglib2.0-bin from apt itself and then run gsettings. This should solve it.

Answer (score 8):

On Xubuntu 18.10 this helps me (I use sakura as a terminal):

```
$ gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec sakura
```

Answer (score 6):

In case you want not to replace, but to **add "Open in Terminator"** in your right-click menu,

1. go to `/home/$USER/.local/share/nemo/actions` folder,
2. create `open_in_terminator.nemo_action`  file:

   ```
   [Nemo Action]

   Name=Open in Terminator
   Comment=Open the 'terminator' terminal in the selected folder
   Exec=terminator --working-directory=%F
   Icon-Name=terminator
   Selection=any
   Extensions=dir;
   EscapeSpaces=true
   ```

Close and re-open Nemo when done adding the file above.

Screenshot of the right-click menu now:

[image]

### Details

From [Gabriel Staples, here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/nemo/open_in_terminator.nemo_action):

> Don't forget `EscapeSpaces=true` or else the "Open in Terminator" action won't work on any folder which has spaces, single quotes (`'`), or double quotes (`"`), within its path.

The [*old* official documentation on that](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/5cea882d0fe20effdba2054c49af827ab8e1af01/files/usr/share/nemo/actions/sample.nemo_action#L99-L106) (which still applies to the version of `nemo` [which can be installed on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446372/327339)) says:

> ```
> # Escape Spaces - set to true to escape spaces in filenames and uris ($U, $F, $P, $D)
> #
> # Sometimes this may be preferred to getting raw filenames that must be enclosed in
> # quotes.
> #
> # Optional - by default this is false
>
> EscapeSpaces=true
> ```

The [*new* documentation](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/master/files/usr/share/nemo/actions/sample.nemo_action#L99-L106) says that this field is deprecated and in future version of Nemo does nothing:

> ```
> # Escape Spaces (deprecated)
> #
> # This field is deprecated and does nothing - paths with spaces, as well as other special
> # shell characters, will now be passed on correctly no matter what, even when Quote is not set.
> #
> # Optional - by default this is false
>
> #EscapeSpaces=true
> ```

### References:

1. [Blog post: "Add Right-Click Commands in Linux Mint / Ubuntu", by Angelos Kyritsis](https://www.pcsteps.com/4434-add-right-click-commands-linux-mint-ubuntu/)
2. [Sample Nemo right-click menu action file from **/usr/share/nemo/actions/sample.nemo_action**](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/master/files/usr/share/nemo/actions/sample.nemo_action)
3. [open_in_terminator.nemo_action](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/nemo/open_in_terminator.nemo_action) file by Gabriel Staples in his [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo.

Comment: I love this answer! But, here's some improvements: 1) change `Comment` to `Comment=Open the 'terminator' terminal in the selected folder`, 2) change `Exec=terminator --working-directory=%P` to `Exec=terminator --working-directory=%F`, and use `Selection=any` and `Extensions=dir;` so that right-clicking on a folder and going to "Open in Terminator" opens it in the selected folder, but right-clicking on files won't give you this option.

Comment: Thanks! I personally have a habit of clicking empty space inside the folder I want to open terminator in, so this solution suited my needs at the time. If you can tweak the solution so it works both for right-clicking on empty space and right-clicking on a folder, that would be great! Feel free to edit all you like :)

Comment: Done: I've edited your answer to match my own `open_in_terminator.nemo_action` file exactly. Now you can also right-click on a folder and choose to open the folder in terminator, as well as still right-click on the background in any folder to open up terminator there too.

Comment: I wanted to approve your edit but also wanted to edit the path (`adminuser -> <user>`) so I chose 'edit' instead of 'approve' and now I don't see how to approve it anymore :(  I hope you get approval from others and the credit you deserve.

Comment: Click the "edited 17 mins ago" link and you'll see my edit in the history already. It must have been approved before you could approve it. The "credit" is only in the edit history, and in these comments here. I'll do one more minor edit to improve that `<user>` line still, so it will work on anyone's machine automtically using the environment variable `$USER`.

Comment: FYI I've added this nemo action file to my GitHub repository here, in case anyone just wants to download it: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/nemo/open_in_terminator.nemo_action

Comment: FYI: When somebody with the authority to approve a suggested edit does “Improve Edit”, that automatically approves the pending edit.  It’s registered as a binding “Approve” vote by the Community♦ pseudo-user; see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/343230).

Comment: @GabrielStaples: What about directories that have ***quotes*** in their names?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', I just checked and tested it: it works fine now in a directory named `~/temp/"test "` (contains space and double quotes).

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' and others: I just did a major revamp to this answer. The old version which quoted `%F` did work on paths with double quotes, but _not_ on paths with single quotes. So, adding `EscapeSpaces=true` fixed it, but that required adding a bunch of extra information to the answer too, which I just did.

Comment: @GabrielStaples:    Use `\`\`\`bash` for Bash commands (e.g., scripts), not for text files in general.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', I want comments to show up as comments. In that configuration file, lines that begin with `#` are comments. If you remove `\`\`\`bash`, it no longer syntax-highlights the comments as comments. So, I recommend putting `\`\`\`bash` back, especially in configuration files like this which have a lot of bash-like syntax and comments which look nice when syntax-highlighted as though they were in a shell script, like Bash.

Answer (score 2):

Find and Open "Preferred Application" in the main menu.

[image: Menu to find Preferred Application]

Choose "Terminator" in the "Preferred Application" dialog.

[image: Preferred Application]

This will set terminator as the default terminal app for the system.

1. You can use "**`CTRL + ALT + T`**" to open terminal.
2. RClick and open context menu in Nemo File Manager in any directory and open the terminal from there.
3. If there is an "arguments" field, change it from "--" to "-x" when using Terminator or you will not be able to execute scripts from Nemo by double clicking.

These will all open Terminator or the default terminal that you've set.

Comment: My "Default Applications" menu in Ubuntu 18.04 just shows this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7gFj.png. You must be running Mint instead? If so, what version? Note that I installed Nemo in Ubuntu following my instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1173861/327339.

Answer (score 2):

First set the default X terminal:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Then you can set the default terminal for cinnamon to this `x-terminal-emulator` (Nemo is the Cinnamon file manager, so it takes its settings from Cinnamon config):

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec x-terminal-emulator
```

Now your desktop environment (eg Gnome) and Cinnamon applications will all use the same terminal, and if you use the first command to change the X terminal in the future, your Cinnamon applications should also use that new terminal.

Comment: Unfortunately, in Ubuntu 18.04 at least, this doesn't work. The first command does but the 2nd one must be `gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec terminator`.

Answer (score 2):

Having wandered into this old thread, I can add my config, as of **2020**. The settings for my system were almost identical:

```
org.cinnamon.desktop.applications.terminal
```

I do not have the `default-` part.

Comment: Yes. for me too. `/org/cinnamon/desktop/applications/terminal/exec`

Answer (score 0):

Nemo determines your default terminal by querying [gsettings](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/GSettings).

To locate all schemas related to "terminal", I did this:

```
gsettings list-schemas | grep terminal
```

For me, that listed these schemas:

```
org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal
org.mate.applications-terminal
org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal
```

Since Nemo is the default file manager of the cinnamon desktop, the first schema (above) is the one we're interested in.

You can determine the current settings of a schema using `gsettings list-recursively schemaPathGoesHere`. For example:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal
```

In my case, this revealed that Nemo is currently using the `x-terminal-emulator`:

```
org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'x-terminal-emulator'
```

To set this to Gnome Terminal (instead), use `gsettings set schemaGoesHere exec 'terminalLaunchCommandGoesHere'`. Like this:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'gnome-terminal'
```